# Symfony - How to override a vendor component which is not in a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, symfony-2.7

I'm searching for override a file which is in the vendor's directory
but is not a bundle.
I'm working with Symfony 2.7

To be more specific, i'm trying to override a method in this file :

```
vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Component/Catalog/Updater/ProductUpdater.php
```

And I'd like to do it in a file like :

```
src/MyApp/Component/Catalog/Updater/ProductUpdater.php
```

All the documentation I've found is relied to parts of a Bundle.
So, is it even possible to do that ?
If it is, how to do it ?

Comment: *it's normal don't worry* - well, no, not really. It sounds like you wanted to fork that project, rather than include it as a dependency of your own.

Comment: How is that file used in your app?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to override a file using composer.

You can add in your composer.json under the autoload->psr-4 key something like this.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Pim\\Component\\Catalog\\Updater\\": "MyApp/Pim/Component/Catalog/Updater"
        },
```

Where the first part is the namespace of the file you want to override and the second part is the new path.

This can create some issues when you add new packages to composer, so make sure you run **composer dump-autoload** to recreated the autoload order.

i don't really like this method, but it did save me a couple of times to fix files from bundles without actually forking the bundle, and if nothing else helps this can me used as a last resort.

More about composer autoload here

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: It doesn't seems to work, I guess I did something bad.

I added this to my composer.json : 
"psr-4": {
            "Pim\\Component\\Catalog\\Updater\\ProductUpdater\\" : "src/MyApp/Bundle/QuantityPackBundle/Updater/ProductUpdater.php"
        }

I also tried with "src/MyApp/Bundle/QuantityPackBundle/Updater/" as path to the override, but it didn't work either.

Comment: I have to precise that I also cleared the cache ect ... :)

Comment: do you get an error on composer dump-autoload? also is Pim\\Component\\Catalog\\Updater\\ProductUpdater\\ the correct namespace for the class you want to override? also make sure src/MyApp/Bundle/QuantityPackBundle/Updater/ProductUpdater.‌​php has the uses the old namespace that you want to override